# Is there a way of viewing the export query run by PHPMyAdmin on a database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am faced with comparing the structures of multiple databases - but not the databases in their entirety, just the tables they all hold in common. I can export their structure via the interface, but have to click through the list of tables each time to define what I want exported. Is there a way I can access the export queries run by PHPMyAdmin in order to simply copy-paste each time?

Comment: You can query [the catalog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html) with the info you need about the table and compare the results of these queries.

Comment: I'm assuming you have different servers too, otherwise it'd be simple (use export template). Do you have access to all databases on the servers, including PMA's own database `phpmyadmin`? If yes, you can create an export template on one, and then export the template itself from `phpmyadmin.pma__export_templates`. Then you can import the template on the next server and then use it to export the actual data. [Note: This works only with PMA 4.5.0+]

Comment: Or, you could use one of the browser extensions [listed here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/extensions-automating-repetitive-browsing-tasks/) to create a macro that fills the export form the way you need, and then run this macro on every server.

Comment: @CherryDT I never copped you could export the templates themselves, which solves my problem handily. If you want to submit this as an answer, I'll mark it accepted. Cheers!

Comment: I didn't originally post it as answer because I don't have PMA handy right now to test it out, it was a strong hunch that it'd work. But if it works for you, great - added as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phpMyAdmin 4.5.0+ supports export templates. On the export screen, you can create an export template with the settings you need. They are per server, but we can do something about that.

By default (this can be configured in PMA's config file), PMA stores these export templates in the database `phpmyadmin` and table `pma__export_templates`.

Provided that you have full access to all databases on your servers, including the `phpmyadmin` one, you can do this:

- Create an export template with the settings you want on one of the servers.
- Export *the export template itself* from the `phpmyadmin.pma__export_templates` table.
- Import the template to `phpmyadmin.pma__export_templates` on the next server.
- Go to the export screen there and load the template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mysqldump --no-data` if you only want to export the metadata.

I did this the other day for a developer at my company who was confused that the staging instance of their database was somehow different from the production instance.

I ran:

```
mysqldump --no-data --skip-add-drop-table --skip-add-locks -h $staging_host > staging-dump.sql
mysqldump --no-data --skip-add-drop-table --skip-add-locks -h $prod_host > prod-dump.sql
```

This dumps just the CREATE TABLE statements. It omits any of the INSERT statements that would contain the data contents of the tables. There's also some comments and some harmless stuff about character sets. Ignore these.

I edited each file in `vim` to remove the AUTO_INCREMENT options from each table creation. Of course these will be different if the number of rows in the tables is different. Here's the `vim` command:

```
:%g/AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]* /s///
```

Then diff the files side-by-side:

```
diff -y staging-dump.sql prod-dump.sql > diff
```

The output shows the files side-by-side (at least as much as it can display), with a single-character column running down the middle between them. The middle column will have `|` to indicate lines that are different, or `<` to indicate lines that exist only in the first file, or `>` to indicate lines that exist only the second file.

Comment: I won't use this right now, but this is something I'll save away!